# Pandas : Merge or Join returns wrong dataFrame

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes I want to merge or join in Python :

"data" :

```
       shortcontentid  hour_timings  not_relevant  other  postman_challenges  \
   0               1           NaN           1.0    NaN                 NaN   
   1               2           NaN           3.0    NaN                 NaN
```

And a dataframe "verbatims" :

```
                                             sentences  shortcontentid
0    Gabe_Newell a écrit : 40 maxi en luminosité ? ...               1
1    J'aime une vidéo @YouTube de @seb_frit - CE ME...               2
```

I want to left-join these frames by the primary key `shortcontentid` which is common to the two frames. As you can see the operation consists in just adding the `sentences` column from the verbatims dataframe to the `data` dataframe.
I do a classic merge :

```
table = data.merge(verbatims, on='shortcontentid', how = "left")
```

but the code won't work or return a wrong dataframe. For instance if I do a print on `table` I will have the values of `verbatims` but not the values of `data`.
Here is an example :

```
     nonusable   2 or bigger sentences  
 0           1       qualite       NaN
```

As you can see `sentences` is filled with NaN whereas I would like to see my actual sentences.

```
*NB : I imported my data from `pandas.csv` : 

data = pandas.read_csv("data crowdflower.csv", sep=";", header=0, engine='python')*
```

What would be the best way to do a clean merge/join on these tables ?

Thanks !

Comment: Explain what doesn't work by posting raw sample data, code to create your dfs and what the incorrect merge looks like

Comment: Alright I edited my post. However I can post sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this form:

```
table = pandas.merge(data, verbatims, how='inner', on='shortcontentid')
print (table)
```

Comment: An inner merge won't work as it returns an empty dataframe with my column names only :

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [shortcontentid, hour_timings, not_relevant, other, postman_challenges, postman_relationship, quality_postman_work, Total g�n�ral, result, nonusable, 2 or bigger, _unit_id, _created_at, _updated_at, brand, sentences]
Index: []`

Answer (score 0):

I have partially understood my problem. `dtype` of shortcontentid in `verbatims` is an integer whereas it is an object in `data`. So I have to convert the dtype from object to int. I tried :

```
pandas.to_numeric(data)
```

but it returns the following error :

```
arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

so I am still blocked.